# What is a good PC sound card for multi-track audio editing?

Tags: editing, audio

I need a good sound card that supports multi-track ASIO editing as well as 7.1 surround sound editing, as my sound editing software requires this. I need it primarily for hardware mixing versus recording, as the sounds I need to mix are already in digital format. In short, I don't need much in the line of inputs, but I do need a lot of streams and the ability to do fast hardware effects. I used to use the Audigy ZS\Pro series which worked well to this purpose, but these have been discontinued.

The PC I want to add the card to is older, but it has PCI and PCI Express slots.

Can anyone recommend a good card that might work for this?

Comment: What software are you using? I bet the vendor may have a good idea about what hardware you can using for hardware effects and mixing

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to mix sounds that already are digital and do fast Fx on them you don't need an special card. Any ASIO card will be enougth. Something like the M-Audio Delta 44 or 66.

Today computers can do ALL the Fx you need. I have a pretty normal Pc running Cubase or ProTools and I have projects plenty of Fx (name more than 200 Vst Fx plugins plus 20 or 30 Vst Generators).

Comment: Seconded. Whereas external or hardware effects requires you to setup your things everytime you load or change project, the joy of software is having all parameters in a single project file. (You just have to make sure the audio files and libraries are at the proper place and installed correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Still using an Audigy ZS myself, but I've read that the successor - [the X-Fi](http://us.creative.com/products/welcomenew.asp?category=209&#subcat669) - is a viable alternative for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've like the Echo cards for sound-recording.  I have an older Layla.  I believe the newer versions will support what you are doing.

http://www.echoaudio.com/Products/PCI/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Digidesign Mbox, which works pretty well for it. It comes with protools LE, and connects via a USB port. Its got no hardware controls but some of the more advanced models have that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used numerous cards from M-Audio, and they seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Im waiting for USB3.0 to become more prominent.  It seems that would finally bring USB recording devices up to par with the PCI devices.   Maybe something will be announced at CES this weekend?